# Telerik RadGridView component: changing the text color in the string "Click here to add new item"

Tags: telerik, radgridview

I want to work with Telerik component: `RadGridView`.

How can I change text color of the "Click here to add new item" string? I thought it was easy to find a solution in Google, but I could not find it.

Comment: Is there anything you tried already? As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could set the GridView's Foreground property to the desired color, but that also changes the color of the text in the rows. To overwrite this, you could add a specific RowStyle. The following code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView
    Foreground="Red"
    GroupRenderMode="Flat"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Countries, Mode=TwoWay}"
    NewRowPosition="Bottom">
    <telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Results in the following:

[image]